# Why I cannot achieve 100% accuracy in my simple training data with CART model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, cart

For experimental purpose, I want to **intentionally over-fit my training data with CART**. But with `rpart` in R. I cannot achieve 100% accuracy. Why?

```
table(d$classes,predict(fit,d, type="class"))   
       1    2
  1 2544   21
  2   33 2402
```

The data is generated from 2 Gaussian, so, **there is no chance the two data points with different class label would overlap**, and we set the complexity parameter to 0 and min split is 1. As discussed in the comment. I tried every combinations with the `control` (not shown in the code), but not helpful.

Why there are still pruning happend on the tree? Or why the tree stop to grow to achivive 100% accuracy?

[image]

---

Code

```
library(mlbench)
library(rpart)
set.seed(0)
graphics.off()
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
d=mlbench.2dnormals(5000,sd=3)

ctr=rpart.control(cp=0,minsplit = 1)
fit=rpart(classes~.,d,control=ctr)
table(d$classes,predict(fit,d, type="class"))

gd=seq(-8,8,0.1)
dnew=expand.grid(x.1=gd,x.2=gd)

plot(d,xlim=c(-8,8),ylim=c(-8,8))
grid()
plot(dnew$x.1,dnew$x.2,col=predict(fit,dnew, type="class"))
plotcp(fit)
grid()
```

Comment: Happy times. I appreciate a person willing to abuse an algorithm knowingly. Not enough `depth` though for this distribution and sample size; the `maxdepth` in `rpart` cannot go above 30. If you used a sample of say 1600, your confusion matrix on  the training-set would be diagonal. (+1 for unruly statistical behaviour)

Comment: gbm is much easier to over-fit.

Comment: @usεr11852 $2^{30}$ is a huge number. and I think the tree we had is far less than 30 depth (As you can see in CP plot, the tree size is <1000). so, the depth may not be a problem?

Comment: Well.. you do use *only* 1509 leafs (`sum((fit$frame$var) == '<leaf>')`). So clearly you are not using that number (or that depth).

Comment: Jokes aside this not a trivial question: I was looking this a bit more carefully and it does not have a good obvious answer. Someone would have to carefully read the C code and I am uncertain it is worth it, my skim-read didn't find anything obvious. They are many points where things could be muddled (eg. `yval` are passed as double so when fitting may unintentionally some aliasing takes place when splitting) but I can't see one *obvious* thing. Maybe you SO this? CV might not maximise your chances for an answer.

Comment: @usεr11852 please check my answer, it verifies your comments!!

Comment: Thank you for pinging me. I wouldn have missed it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason: it is the `maxdepth` problem as suggested by @usεr11852.

We thought max depth is $30$ is a big enough, since $2^{30}$ is a huge number. However, in many cases, depth $30$ is not enough since the tree is not a complete binary tree, which has $2^n$ terminal nodes, if we have $n$ layer.

---

Here is the verification:

There is a hidden function in `rpart` can produce the depth of the tree. As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897081/how-can-i-get-the-depth-of-the-tree-in-rpart-model).

```
nodes=as.numeric(rownames(fit$frame))
max(rpart:::tree.depth(nodes))
```

Using this function we can get the tree size is $30$ !! And if we plot it, it also verifies the results and from the figure we can see, the tree is far away from complete binary tree.

[image]

---

What we learned from this experiment:

RPART documentation on max depth says:

> Set the maximum depth of any node of the final tree, with the root node counted as depth 0. Values greater than 30 rpart will give nonsense results on 32-bit machines.

**This may not be accurate, since the tree can be far away from complete binary tree, so, values than 30 will make since in many cases !! and it should allow user to set a bigger number**

Comment: +1 because it is quite useful but I am a bit uncertain that you answer the question fully... You answer the question of the *where* you get the pruning not *how* or *why* the pruning happens. For example simply rewriting `rpart.control` to accept `maxdepth` arguments above 30, say 130, does not suffice to use a larger tree proprely. It really seems that something is hard-coded within the C code of `rpart` as using `maxdepth` larger than 30+ produces `fit$frame$yval` that has zeros (effectively predicting a third class - nice undefined behaviour there).