# Decision tree does not overfit, why?

Tags: r, cart, overfitting, caret

The following code trains multiple decision trees on synthetic data with varying complexity:

```
library(caret)

d<-twoClassSim(10000, intercept = -10, linearVars = 10, noiseVars = 10 )
c<-trainControl(method="cv",summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,classProbs=T,allowParallel = F) 
train(Class~.,data=d, method="rpart", trControl=tc, tuneGrid = expand.grid(cp=c(2^-seq(1:24),0)), metric="ROC")
```

These are the results:

```
CART 

10000 samples
   25 predictor
   2 classes: 'Class1', 'Class2' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 9001, 9001, 9000, 9000, 9000, 9000, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

cp            ROC        Sens       Spec     
0.000000e+00  0.8720221  0.9175038  0.6351468
5.960464e-08  0.8693352  0.9178879  0.6338036
1.192093e-07  0.8693352  0.9178879  0.6338036
2.384186e-07  0.8693352  0.9178879  0.6338036
4.768372e-07  0.8693352  0.9178879  0.6338036
9.536743e-07  0.8693352  0.9178879  0.6338036
1.907349e-06  0.8693352  0.9178879  0.6338036
3.814697e-06  0.8693352  0.9178879  0.6338036
7.629395e-06  0.8693352  0.9178879  0.6338036
1.525879e-05  0.8693352  0.9178879  0.6338036
3.051758e-05  0.8693352  0.9178879  0.6338036
6.103516e-05  0.8693352  0.9178879  0.6338036
1.220703e-04  0.8688977  0.9184034  0.6338036
2.441406e-04  0.8695238  0.9190479  0.6333571
4.882812e-04  0.8683167  0.9199503  0.6346964
9.765625e-04  0.8642201  0.9234327  0.6275635
1.953125e-03  0.8502711  0.9358066  0.6061528
3.906250e-03  0.8170988  0.9421235  0.5776111
7.812500e-03  0.7992001  0.9391563  0.5624742
1.562500e-02  0.7309271  0.9416099  0.4928790
3.125000e-02  0.7279783  0.9249799  0.5267897
6.250000e-02  0.7279783  0.9249799  0.5267897
1.250000e-01  0.6607248  0.9497346  0.3688948
2.500000e-01  0.5000000  1.0000000  0.0000000
5.000000e-01  0.5000000  1.0000000  0.0000000

ROC was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was cp = 0.0002441406.
```

Clearly, the decision tree has it's highest ROC AUC with complexity parameter  0 indicating that it does not overfit at all. How can that be explained? Is this plausible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `rpart` package, in addition to `cp`, parameter `minsplit`, `minbucket` and `maxdepth` also has default values, that will prevent over fit every instance.

Try to set `minsplit=1` and `minbucket=1`.

A related discussion can be found here.

[Why I cannot achieve 100% accuracy in my simple training data with CART model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248706/why-i-cannot-achieve-100-accuracy-in-my-simple-training-data-with-cart-model)